# Error: 175002 (RA layer request failed)

Tags: xcode, version-control, mercurial

I get the following error when connecting XCode to a repository on GoogleCode.com

```
Error: 175002 (RA layer request failed) Description: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://touchcode.googlecode.com/hg'
```

Has anyone see this before and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using http protocol for accessing svn , try using svn://repoaddress/

In my case the protocol was incorrect.

Comment: The repository in question is a Mercurial repository, so no variety of using Subversion to access it will work.

Answer (score 2):

That's a Mercurial repository. You can't use Subversion (or Xcode's Subversion integration, which counts as the same thing) to access a Mercurial repository.

Xcode has no Mercurial integration, so you are just going to have to clone the repository outside of Xcode, using either Mercurial directly or a GUI Mercurial client such as Murky or MacHg.